# Extending SqlMembershipProvider DataBase

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization, membership-provider

I'm trying to implement an ASP.NET app with different kind of users and a lot of business entities.

I thought that extending the default SqlMembershipProvider is the way to go.

So, What's the best way to extend the default ASP.NET SqlMembershipProvider to add more fields and logic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly used the new ASN.net Identity and that solved the problem